# stripe checkout css content policy error

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a form of [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) inside my Ionic App. i've created a Directive that plant the form into my content view, but when i run it, the css fails on content policy violation:

> checkout.js:2Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/checkout/button-qpwW2WfkB0oGWVWIASjIOQ.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". append @
>   checkout.js:2Button.append @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @
>   checkout.js:2Button.load @ checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @
>   checkout.js:2(anonymous function) @ checkout.js:2

no matter what i define in my meta tag of content policy, it's just not working
what do i do wrong?

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' localhost:* https://bnc.lt https://api.branch.io amazonaws.com amazonaws.com.cn checkout.stripe.com 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `style-src` allows for `self` and `unsafe-inline` it should also allow for `https://checkout.stripe.com`

Comment: thank u!
i've added:
content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://checkout.stripe.com ; .....

Comment: where is this added? in the Javaconfiguration file or the index .html of an application?

Comment: where is this added?