# Ruby on Rails: Stripe JS & Elements causing Content Security Policy error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app where I'm planning to integrate Stripe payments. I'm using the `stripe` gem. I'm planning to use Elements, as [described here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js).

I'm including Stripe js like this:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/'
```

In my `charges.coffee` file I have this:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.secrets['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>")
  elements = stripe.elements()
```

When I load the app I currently get the following error in Safari:

`Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.`

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: we should solve this issue by reading together this posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502307/chrome-18-how-to-allow-inline-scripting-with-a-content-security-policy#11672134 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489518/stripe-checkout-css-content-policy-error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this today by upgrading secure_headers gem from v3 to the latest v5 and my illogical CSP errors went away.